# Combine two text files with powershell

Tags: powershell

I have two text files with data.

First text file contains a big list of fullpaths to my files.
d:\cat\cat1.txt

```
d:\test\file1-1.txt
d:\test\file1-2.txt
....
d:\test\file1-N.txt
```

Second text file contains a short list of fullpath to my \files

d:\cat\file\cat2.txt

```
d:\test\file2-1.txt
d:\test\file2-2.txt
```

I need third file which contains

```
d:\test\file1-1.txt
d:\test\file1-2.txt
d:\test\file2-1.txt
d:\test\file1-3.txt
d:\test\file1-4.txt
d:\test\file2-2.txt
d:\test\file1-5.txt
d:\test\file1-6.txt
d:\test\file2-1.txt
```

Thx for help.

Comment: Your going to need to explain the rule for sorting the output. We can only guess.

Answer (score 15):

If you  want to combine multiple files ( 2 or more ), you can do:

```
gc d:\cat\cat1.txt,d:\cat\file\cat2.txt | out-file d:\cat\combinedcat.txt
```

It is not clear from your example what kind of "specific" combination you want, so you may want to explain that, but the logic for combining files will be like above.

Comment: If you want to combine all text files in a path, try: gc C:\Path\*.txt | Out-file C:\Path\MergedTextFile.txt

Comment: this is sllooooowwwwwwww - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17749058/combine-multiple-text-files-into-one-text-file-using-python#17749339

Answer (score 4):

Get the content of both files and save output to a new file:

```
Get-ChildItem d:\cat\cat1.txt,d:\cat\file\cat2.txt | 
  Get-Content | Out-File d:\cat\cat3.txt
```

Comment: Why is it - when I have only 3 short files and I replace Get-ChildItem with Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Filter *.txt it actually adds those file in an endless loop?

Comment: @MauriceKlimek I'm getting the endless loop issue as well