# combine multiple text files into one text file using python

Tags: python

suppose we have many text files as follows:

file1:

```
abc
def
ghi
```

file2:

```
ABC
DEF
GHI
```

file3:

```
adfafa
```

file4:

```
ewrtwe
rewrt
wer
wrwe
```

How can we make one text file like below:

result:

```
abc
def
ghi
ABC
DEF
GHI
adfafa
ewrtwe
rewrt
wer
wrwe
```

Related code may be:

```
import csv
import glob
files = glob.glob('*.txt')
for file in files:
with open('result.txt', 'w') as result:
result.write(str(file)+'\n')
```

After this? Any help?

Comment: this thread is a ducplicate of 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13613336/python-concatenate-text-files

Comment: `cat *.txt > all.txt`

Answer (score 89, accepted):

You can read the content of each file directly into the write method of the output file handle like this:

```
import glob

read_files = glob.glob("*.txt")

with open("result.txt", "wb") as outfile:
    for f in read_files:
        with open(f, "rb") as infile:
            outfile.write(infile.read())
```

Comment: thank you. i accepted your answer because your code is powerful. since i am new, can you explain infile.read() procedure.@apiguy

Comment: The `.read()` method of a file handle reads the contents of a file and produces a string of it's contents.

Comment: nice one apiguy!!

Comment: Is there a way to do it column wise?

Comment: The most effective way I came across. Thank you :)

Comment: `import glob; outfile = open("out.txt", "wb"); [outfile.write(open(f, "rb").read()) for f in glob.glob("*.txt")]` just for the fun of having a one-liner :)

Answer (score 21):

The `fileinput` module is designed perfectly for this use case.

```
import fileinput
import glob

file_list = glob.glob("*.txt")

with open('result.txt', 'w') as file:
    input_lines = fileinput.input(file_list)
    file.writelines(input_lines)
```

Comment: That's probably the most efficient method and works perfectly in Python 2.7

Comment: The risk with this code is that if you already have a `result.txt` file (say, you're running it a second time), the process never ends and builds an ever-increasing sized file.

Answer (score 9):

You could try something like this:

```
import glob
files = glob.glob( '*.txt' )

with open( 'result.txt', 'w' ) as result:
    for file_ in files:
        for line in open( file_, 'r' ):
            result.write( line )
```

Should be straight forward to read.

Answer (score 1):

It is also possible to combine files by incorporating OS commands. Example:

```
import os
import subprocess
subprocess.call("cat *.csv > /path/outputs.csv")
```

Comment: This is not portable approach.

Comment: This is the answer that worked for me! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
filenames = ['resultsone.txt', 'resultstwo.txt']
with open('resultsthree', 'w') as outfile:
    for fname in filenames:
        with open(fname) as infile:
            for line in infile:
                outfile.write(line)
```

Comment: add some explanation to your answer.

Comment: line by line reading/writing a file is not the same as reading / writing the bytes of a file. just FYI.