# Iterating files in directory by name

Tags: python, loops, directory

Ok, I have a directory with many files and subdirectories; among these ones there are 20 directories called `mbr001`, `mbr002`, ... until `mbr020` that are the ones I am interested in.

I want to write a program that iteratively goes into `mbr001`, do somethings, then to `mbr002`, do the same things, and so on.

A solution with Python's `os.chdir('./mbr001')` until 20 seems pretty inefficient.

Besides, when I am in such directories, let's say for example `mbr012`, I want to create a variable that has in its name the number of the mbr where I am, in this case 12. Something like `variable = 'mbr012_file.dat'`. (This `variable` is used in what I am doing inside each directory, not relevant here).

What I would need would be something like this (note this is pseudo-code):

```
for i in mbr[i]:
    variable = "mbr[i]_file.dat"
    ...
```

How can I do the loop and the variable naming? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that `i` is both the loop variable *and* used to get the items to loop over?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like this ?

```
for i in range(1, 21):
    dn =  "./mbr{:03}".format(i)
    var = "mbr{:03}_file.dat".format(i)
    os.chdir(dn)
    # Do your stuff here
    #
    #
    os.chdir("..")
```

Comment: `listdir` might not be want he wants to do and the `range` should be defined as `range(1, 21)` or use `i+1` instead of `i`. i would simpy suggest using absolute paths instead of relative ones to avoid having to `chdir` everytime

Comment: @Ev.Kounis I agree about your absolute path advise. But since there is no information about operations to do in those folders, i will keep it like thise for now.

Comment: What I am doing is to concatenate all the files in each `mbr...` directory; indeed using the solution from this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17749484/python-script-to-concatenate-all-the-files-in-the-directory-into-one-file The variable `outfilename` is what it would be here `var`.

Comment: I am checking @C.LECLERC 's solution. The size of my directories is pretty big...

Comment: Thank you. The solution is working but there seems to be a problem with the {:03} part. The file is named with a {:03}, not with the 001, or 010 or 020... as expected for each directory.

Comment: Ah, forget about this last comment. I forgot the `format(i)` in the `var`. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
for i in list_of_is:
    filename = "mbr{0:02d}_file.dat".format(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to concatenate '_files.dat' into the directory name

```
import re
for i in mbr_list:
    variable = i + '_files.dat'
    # use regex if you only interest on the numeric part
    # variable = re.sub('mbr(\d+)', r'mbr\1_file.dat', i)
    # do your thing here
```

Comment: Thank you. I assume the _list part converts to a list the integers. I didn't know of this trick.

Comment: Just notice, actually shouldn't just variable = i +  '_file.dat' will do ?

Answer (score 1):

In python 3.4 and above you can use [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) and in python 3.6 and above you can use "[f string](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/)" to format text

```
from pathlib import Path

for path in [d for d in Path.cwd().iterdir() if d.match("mbr*")]:
    variable = f"{path.name}_file.dat"
    # do other stuff
```