# Reading text files into lists in Python

Tags: python, list, file

Instead of defining `documents`like this ...

```
documents = ["the mayor of new york was there", "machine learning can be useful sometimes","new york mayor was present"]
```

... I want to read the same three sentences from two different txt files with the first sentence in the first file, and sentence 2 and 3 in the second file.

I have come up with this code:

```
# read txt documents
os.chdir('text_data')
documents = []
for file in glob.glob("*.txt"): # read all txt files in working directory
    file_content = open(file, "r")
    lines = file_content.read().splitlines()
    for line in lines:
        documents.append(line)
```

But the `documents` resulting from the two strategies seem to be in different format. I want the second strategy to produce the same output as the first.

Comment: ... what is wrong? Please try to be specific with your problem statements.

Comment: Edited for clarity.

Comment: My point was that instead of writing "the `documents`  resulting form the two strategies seem to be in different format" you should instead *show the output*

Comment: Also, doing this: `lines = file_content.read().splitlines()` is not necessary. You can iterate directly over the file handler, and it iterates over lines. So just `for line in file_content:` would be sufficient (although you'll get the trailing newlines). Likely, you just want `documents.append(file_content.read())` And you don't have to iterate over the file at all...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [combine multiple text files into one text file using python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17749058/combine-multiple-text-files-into-one-text-file-using-python)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your code correctly, this is equivalent and more performant (no reading the entire file into a string, then splitting to a list).

```
os.chdir('text_data')
documents = []
for file in glob.glob("*.txt"): # read all txt files in working directory
    documents.extend( line for line in open(file) )
```

Or maybe even one line.

```
documents = [ line for line in open(file) for file in glob.glob("*.txt") ]
```

Comment: you need to reverse the order of the "for"s in the list comprehension

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `.read().splitlines()`, you can use `.readlines()`. This will place every file's contents into a list.

Comment: I am new to stack overflow, @juanpa.arrivillaga. What I meant was that the contents of the list that .readlines() creates could be further appended to documents, but I see that your most recent comment answered what I was trying to explain. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> ... I want to read the same three sentences from two different txt
>   files with the first sentence in the first file, and sentence 2 and 3
>   in the second file.

Translating the requirements directly gives:

```
with open('somefile1.txt') as f1:
    lines_file1 = f1.readlines()
with open('somefile2.txt') as f2:
    lines_file2 = f2.readlines()
documents = lines_file1[0:1] + lines_file2[1:3]
```

FWIW, given the kind of work you're doing, the `[fileinput module][1]` may be helpful.

Hope this get you back in business :-)