# Python - pair lines from 2 files with \n

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to Python. I have two files that have sentences that I need to combine 2 files line by line into a single file.

```
file_1.txt: 
feel my cold hands.
I love oranges. 
Mexico has a large surplus of oil.
Ink stains don't rub out.

file_2.txt: 
≥ª ¬˘ º’¿ª ¡ª ∏∏¡Æ∫¡.
∏«¸ ∫Ò«‡±‚∞° ∞≠¿ª ≥Øæ∆∞¨¥Ÿ.
∏ﬂΩ√ƒ⁄ø°¥¬ ¥Ÿ∑Æ¿« ø©∫–¿« ºÆ¿Ø∞° ¿÷¥Ÿ.
¿◊≈© ¿⁄±π¿∫ ¥€æ∆µµ ¡ˆøˆ¡ˆ¡ˆ æ ¥¬¥Ÿ.



FINAL OUTPUT should look like: 

feel my cold hands.
≥ª ¬˘ º’¿ª ¡ª ∏∏¡Æ∫¡.

I love oranges. 
∏«¸ ∫Ò«‡±‚∞° ∞≠¿ª ≥Øæ∆∞¨¥Ÿ.

Mexico has a large surplus of oil.
∏ﬂΩ√ƒ⁄ø°¥¬ ¥Ÿ∑Æ¿« ø©∫–¿« ºÆ¿Ø∞° ¿÷¥Ÿ.

Ink stains don't rub out.
¿◊≈© ¿⁄±π¿∫ ¥€æ∆µµ ¡ˆøˆ¡ˆ¡ˆ æ ¥¬¥Ÿ.
```

Here is what I tried

```
filenames = ['data/data.txt', 'data/data2.txt']
with open('data/test.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for fname in filenames:
        with open(fname) as infile:
            for line in infile:
                outfile.write(line)
```

This code here just concats the files one after another. However, it is not paring up the line by line and creating \n.
Thanks!!

References: 
[combine multiple text files into one text file using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17749058/combine-multiple-text-files-into-one-text-file-using-python)

[Python concatenate text files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13613336/python-concatenate-text-files)

Comment: Does the number of input files change?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So the trick is we want to iterate over both files simultaneously. To do that we can use the `zip` function like so:

```
filenames = ['data/data.txt', 'data/data2.txt']
with open('data/test.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    with open(filenames[0]) as f1, open(filenames[1]) as f2:
        for f1_line, f2_line in zip(f1, f2):
            outfile.write(f1_line)
            outfile.write(f2_line)
            outfile.write("\n")  # add blank line between each pair
```

Comment: With `outfile.write('\n')` at the end to answer OP's question in 100%.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this:

```
with open('data/data.txt', 'r') as f1, open('data/data2.txt', 'r') as f2:
    for line1, line2 in zip(f1, f2):
        # do something
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a context manager:

```
import contextlib

@contextlib.contextmanager
def aline(outfile, *files):
  final_data = zip(open(files[0]), open(files[1]))
  yield ['\n'.join([a, b]) for a, b in final_data]
  f = open(outfile, 'w')
  for a, b in final_data:
    f.write('\n'.join([a, b])+'\n\n')
  f.close()

with aline('output.txt', *['data/data.txt', 'data/data2.txt']) as f:
  print(f)
```

Output (int `output.txt`):

```
feel my cold hands.
≥ª ¬˘ º’¿ª ¡ª ∏∏¡Æ∫¡.

I love oranges. 
∏«¸ ∫Ò«‡±‚∞° ∞≠¿ª ≥Øæ∆∞¨¥Ÿ.

Mexico has a large surplus of oil.
∏ﬂΩ√ƒ⁄ø°¥¬ ¥Ÿ∑Æ¿« ø©∫–¿« ºÆ¿Ø∞° ¿÷¥Ÿ.

Ink stains don't rub out.
¿◊≈© ¿⁄±π¿∫ ¥€æ∆µµ ¡ˆøˆ¡ˆ¡ˆ æ ¥¬¥Ÿ.
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
filenames = ['data/data.txt', 'data/data2.txt']
with open('data/test.txt', 'w') as outfile,ExitStack() as stack:
    files = [stack.enter_context(open(fname)) for fname in filenames]
    for lines in zip(*files):
        outfile.writelines(lines)
```

This approach can take any number of inputfiles.